# python multithreaded sniffer- exit from thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have created a packet sniffer in python using scapy but kind of stuck in the multithreaded stuff..

```
def sniffer(ip):
    filter_str = "icmp and host " + ip
    packets=sniff(filter=filter_str,count=20)
    status= False
    for p in packets:
        packet_load=str(p['Raw'].load)
        if packet_load.find("@@")!= -1:
                status=True
                log_thread = Thread(target=logger,args=(packets,))
                log_thread.start()
                log_thread.join()
                break
    if status==True:
        print "Suspicious Packets sniffed!!"

    user_ip = raw_input("Do you want to continue sniffing???(y/n)")
    while 1:
        if user_ip=="y" or user_ip=="Y":
            new_thread = Thread(target=sniffer, args=(ip,))
            new_thread.start()
            new_thread.join()
        else:
            #need somthing to quit the program
   return
```

Here, my sniffer sniffs 20 packets at a time and waits for user input for further sniffing.
However if the user enters 'n' as input, then the program hangs. Ideally I would want the program to quit if the user enters 'n'. Can I know what I'm doing wrong here??

Comment: The break statement doesn't work if the user enters 'y' the first time and then 'n' since multiple threads would have been created and the program still hangs

Comment: Correct, I just realized this and removed my earlier suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while 1` is rarely a good choice when writing a finite loop. Try using flags instead:

```
leaving = False
while not leaving:

    user_ip = raw_input("Do you want to continue sniffing???(y/n)")
    if user_ip.lower() == 'y':
        new_thread = Thread(target=sniffer, args=(ip,))
        new_thread.start()
        new_thread.join()
    elif user_ip.lower() == 'n':
        print "Leaving sniffer"
        leaving = True
return
```